# Datatables length undefined

Tags: php, json, ajax, datatables

I am trying to get some data via ajax from a php file and display them with the Datatables. This is just an example before using it.

My js looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "ajax.php?action=testAjax"
} );
} );
```

my php file has a function

```
function testAjax(){
header('Content-type: application/json');
$arr = array();
$arr['draw'] = 1;
$arr['recordsTotal'] = 1;
$arr['recordsFiltered'] = 1;
$arr['data'] = [array('id', 'name', 'age', 'address', 'tel')];

 return json_encode($arr);
}
```

the output looks like this:

```
{
"draw":1,
"recordsTotal":1,
"recordsFiltered":1,
"data":[["id","name","age","address","tel"]]
}
```

I was following the docu of the Datatables and tried to build the JSON. But i am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

whats the problem? its exactly the same JSON output like in the docu...

Comment: That does not look like the current version of Datatables. Are you looking at old documentation or using an old version?

Comment: I am sure I saw this question about an hour ago

Comment: Use the uncompressed version of DataTables and follow the error. Do you have a line number or anything?

Comment: Why is it `"iTotalRecords"`? I have `"recordsTotal"`. Same for other fields.

Comment: They dropped the Hungarian notation in 1.10 I think it was. Though there is some backward compatibility. OP should look at newer examples probably.

Comment: i was following this: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side, but realized it may be old so i followed this now: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html, and edited my question. Its still the same error...

Comment: Is your output a string or actual json? You're not setting content type in your headers

Comment: @PatrickQ i forgot to edit it. The error is the same~

Comment: @Kisaragi the output come in "" but when i copy and paste it in https://jsonlint.com/ it says its a valid json. How and where to set the content type?

Comment: It is valid json, but the server could respond by with text instead, in your PHP function  try setting : `header('Content-type: application/json')`

Comment: @Kisaragi tried it. No change. Still the same error... also edited it in my question